# Value of boolean type changed in C

Tags: c, boolean, scanf

I noticed that in C, my boolean variable somehow gets changed in a way I don't understand.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(void) {
   bool x, y;

   printf("x: ");
   scanf("%d", &x);

   printf("x is %d\n", x);

   printf("y: ");
   scanf("%d", &y);

   printf("x is %d\n", x);
   printf("y is %d\n", y);

   return 0;
}
```

If I input a value of `1` for `x` and any value for `y` (`1` in this example):

> ```
> x: 1
> x is 1
> y: 1
> x is 0
> y is 1
> ```

at the end, `y` outputs the correct original value, but `x` magically changes to `0` in between!

This is not a problem when the input for `x` is `0` since the outputs for both `x` and `y` are their respective original values as expected.

Please explain what is going on!

Comment: Sidenote: Always check return value of `scanf` functions. Otherwise you will experience *undefined behaviour* when user gives invalid (in this case non-numeric) input.

Comment: Save time, enable complier warnings.  `bool x, y; ... scanf("%d", &x);` should have warned you.

Comment: @chux I agree, I added this as an answer.

Answer (score 8):

You are passing address of boolean variable to `scanf()` which expects variable of type `int*`. This will invoke undefined behavior and you may get wrong results or even crash.

To solve this problem, use temporary `int` to store scanning of an boolean value (as int), and after that store it to boolean variable.

**Demo**

```
bool x, y;
int tmp;

printf("x: ");
scanf("%d", &tmp);
x = tmp;
```

On the other hand, printing boolan variable is different story, where boolean value is protomoted to int without any problems and printed correctly.

Comment: `x = (tmp != 0 ? true : false);` z-> `x = !!tmp;`

Answer (score 7):

OK, two points here.

1. The size of `bool` is implementation-defined.
2. There is no format specifier defined for `bool` type in the standard.

So, while **scanning** the value, passing the address of a `bool` as the argument for `%d` is bad <sup>see note</sup> as the supplied type is not the same as expected type.

You can use a intermediate integer, scan the value into that and (after validation or transformation to `true` and `false` MACROs) assign the result back to `bool` type variable.

For **printing**, however, because of default argument promotion, a `bool` can be a candidate for the argument for `%d` without a problem.

---

Note:

`%d` with `*scanf()` expects the argument to be an `int *`, instead supplying a `bool*` will cause  [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Related, quoting from chapter §7.21.6.2, Paragraph 10

> [....] Unless assignment suppression was indicated by a `*`, the
>   result of the conversion is placed in the object pointed to by the first argument following
>   the `format` argument that has not already received a conversion result. **If this object
>   does not have an appropriate type, or if the result of the conversion cannot be represented
>   in the object, the behavior is undefined.**

Comment: Could you explain more on how "passing the address of a bool as the argument for `%d` is not good"?

Comment: This one is maybe helpful: `printf("\n_Bool: %zu\nint: %zu", sizeof(_Bool), sizeof(int));` showing that they may not have the same size. On my machine (gcc 4.8.5) I get: `_Bool: 1` and `int: 4`.

Comment: @AndreKampling not hugely relevant as it is still undefined behaviour to use mismatching format specifier even for two types that have the same size

Comment: @M.M to expand, like , for  `int` and `float`. The alignment also plays a role.

Comment: @M.M also, edited the last part to make it clearer, is it better?

Comment: @M.M sir, even if `bool` is a `typedef` for an `int`?

Comment: @M.M if I may, it need not be an `int *`, strictly, it can be a pointer to a signed integer type. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @M.M Thanks for correcting then, I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 7):

A `bool` isn't an `int`.  Reading it with the `%d` format specifier for an `int` is undefined behavior.

Per **7.21.6.2  The `fscanf` function**, paragraph 13 [of the C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined.

Note that paragraph 9 of **7.21.6.1  The `fprintf` function** states:

> If  a  conversion  specification  is  invalid,  the  behavior  is 
>   undefined. If  any argument  is not  the  correct  type  for  the 
>   corresponding  conversion  specification,  the  behavior  is
>   undefined.

But that's for `fprintf()`, not `fscanf()`.  Format specifiers are much more stringent for the `scanf()` functions as there will be no argument promotion that 
allows a format such as `%d` to "work" for a `char` or `bool`, which get promoted to `int` for a `printf()` call.  The `scanf()` functions are passed the *address* of the argument, and if what the address refers to is the wrong size from what is expected per the format specifier, undefined behavior will result - such as unexplained changes to *another* variable.

Comment: This is **wrong**. The conversion specification is __not invalid__ here. see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45588405/2173917)

Comment: @SouravGhosh How do you know?

Comment: @SouravGhosh: but isn't this exactly what you are saying in your answer ???

Comment: @PaulR no sir, the conversion specification is __fine__, it's the argument that's mismatching there.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Huh? Obviously people mean "the conversion specifier is wrong for the argument provided"

Comment: @SouravGhosh: the point is that the conversion specification and the type of the parameter don't match. It's a perfectly good answer if you read it carefully.

Comment: @SouravGhosh *no sir, the conversion specification is fine, it's the argument that's mismatching there.*  How can the conversion specification be "fine" if it doesn't match the argument?  That's the **definition** of an invalid conversion specification:  "under control
of the string pointed to by
format
that specifies the admissible input sequences and how
they are  to  be  converted  for  assignment,  using  subsequent  arguments  as  pointers  to  the
objects to receive the converted input."

Comment: @PaulR wrong and invalid are used in different context, as I read it. Also, i have linked a question of mine in this context.

Comment: @user694733 That's an explanatory footnote.  And [in this copy of the C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), footnote 282 reads "282) See ‘‘future library directions’’ (7.31.11)."

Comment: First off I just started learning C two days ago, so I don't understand 90% of the things in that PDF. Also, these comments are just making me more confused as to what is cause of the problem. For now it sounds like an issue of semantics to me.

Comment: @user694733 OK, you're quoting the `fprintf()` section, paragraph 9.  That following sentence isn't in paragraph 13 of the `fscanf()` section that I quoted.  I'd think the `fscanf()` section is more appropriate, especially since `fprintf()` format specifiers *de facto* allow a lot of "slop" because of argument promotion, which won't help with any of the `scanf()` functions.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I feel like an idiot now :P Sorry. Deleteting comments.

Comment: @user694733  That was useful, and probably explains some of the *other* comments - and misguided downvotes, as there is *no* reference to the argument not being the correct type for the conversion specification in the ***fscanf*** section of the standard.

Comment: Reading the `fscanf` docs, I still think there may be an issue. I think you should've quoted paragraph 10, specifically *"... If this object
does not have an appropriate type, or ..., the behavior is undefined"*. I believe paragraph 13 covers only malformed conversion specifier syntax (like non-existent `%k`).

Comment: @user694733 I'm going to have to re-read paragraph 10 now.  :-/  I had viewed that as referring to the *processing* of the input data but at the end it does move on to addressing the storing of the conversion results.

Comment: Good that this answer emphasizes `%d` matches not a `bool` or `int`, but an `int *`.

Answer (score 5):

`bool` is a different data type then `int`, and it is likely to be a single byte.

`scanf` is not type-safe function, you are telling it with the `%d` conversion specifier that expects **pointer to an int**, and `scanf` has no way to know that you have passed `pointer to bool` instead of **pointer to an int**. Then, you will get **undefined behaviour**.

**clang** compiler generated warning:

```
source_file.c:8:16: warning: format specifies type 'int *' but the argument has type 'bool *' [-Wformat]
   scanf("%d", &x);
          ~~   ^~
source_file.c:13:16: warning: format specifies type 'int *' but the argument has type 'bool *' [-Wformat]
   scanf("%d", &y);
          ~~   ^~
```

Answer (score 3):

All the other answers are technically correct, but don't really help you.

Your main problem is not x nor y, but the fact that you are unable to debug the most trivial programming problems yourself. This is easy to fix - enable compiler warnings (if using `gcc`, add `-Wall` option). Compiler will inform you about a mistake like this, and many-many more. No need to come to stackoverflow every time :)

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(void) {
  int z, s;
  printf("int  z: %p\nint  s: %p\n", &z, &s);

  bool x, y;
  printf("bool x: %p\nbool y: %p\n", &x, &y);

  return 0;
}
```

The output:

```
int  z: 0028FF3C
int  s: 0028FF38
bool x: 0028FF37
bool y: 0028FF36
```

Now, between `z` and `s` there is a 4 byte difference which is the size of an `int` in my case.

Between `x` and `y` there is only 1 byte difference.

Now with this line:

```
scanf("%d", &y);
```

You are telling with the `%d` to `scanf` that you want require a 4 byte long input, an `int`.

This `int` will be stored in case of `y` from the address `0028FF36` and with an input of `0x0001` the second byte which is a `0` will be stored at `0028FF37`. And that is the address of `x`.

You can check it with another input value. For example if you give `65535` to `y` which is `0xFFFF` then `x` will be `0xF`, which is `255` decimal.

Comment: Do you know about `sizeof` ?

Comment: @M.M I found it more illustrative this way.

Answer (score 0):

or maybe (if input string contains true or is 1 will return `1` - otherwise `0`)

```
int getBool(char *message)
{
    char input[20];
    printf("%s", message);
    fgets(input, 20, stdin);
    return !!strstr(strlwr(input), "true") || strtol(input, NULL, 10);
}
```

Comment: Without the `!!`, the return value would be the same.  A style issue, I guess.

Comment: in this case yes